# Simple data fetch from SQL Server takes too long - .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlperformance

I have this simple view class in .NET:

```
public partial class vw_ViewFromMSSQL : BaseSQL
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public long databaseid { get; set; }
        public long prop2 { get; set; }
        public long prop3 { get; set; }
```

where `BaseSQL` is:

```
public abstract class BaseSQL
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long ID { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid UUID { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have this simple LINQ which should return me the data for given `databaseid`:

```
var data = await _context.vw_ViewFromMSSQL
                .Where(x => x.databaseid == databaseid )
                .Select(x=> new DTOClass()
                {
                    ID = fks.ID,
                    databaseid = x.databaseid,
                    prop2 = x.prop2,
                    prop3 = x.prop3
                }).ToListAsync();
```

Now this `data` fetches data in ~10 seconds even though it should return only 150 rows. However if I run the query in SQL Server, I get results in 1 second. I have tons of other calls like this related to other views but they return the result much more faster than this. This view has indexes, it has every column described in the class. Another thing to note is that all of the calls go through `Task` so they're `async` calls.

This is kind of more of a discussion than a question but what could be the reason for this slow fetch and is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: You need to run the SQL Server Profiler and see what query is actually being sent to SQL Server, and then you can tune that.

Comment: The answer to "what could be the reason for this slow fetch" is that LINQ to SQL is dumb. I don't mean you're dumb for trying to use it. I mean Microsoft was foolish to believe they could protect developers working with a SQL database from having to learn any SQL. Writing performant SQL is already both science and art, thinking it could be autogenerated from a totally different language was misguided.

Comment: Hm, I see. Thanks for the answers guys, this thing is retarded, when I filter by other prop it gets the results faster even though it gets x3 times more rows

Comment: For better performance help, we need to see the query plan (you can share it via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and the table and index definitions. Unless this is an indexed view, it doesn't have an index, we need to see the base tables

Answer (score 0):

The abstract class `BaseSql` already has `ID` & `UUID` as property.
Why also add `ID` to `vw_ViewFromMSSQL` which already comes by inheriting from the base class?

You can also turn on logging, so you can see the underlying query.

Did you try without mapping to DTO? So just:

```
var data = await _context.vw_ViewFromMSSQL
                         .Where(x => x.databaseid == databaseid )
                         .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I tried it without DTO, still the same. Weird